# how to sav blob as a imagefile in couch db?

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb

I am using couchdb with jquery couch api.
While uploading profile pic in my website, I am giving image as a file to attachment.
it saves attachment as follows:

```
"_attachments": {
       "imagename.jpg": {
           "content_type": "image/jpeg",
           "revpos": 2,
           "digest": "md5-Tt+1bbCmDqSFbVlZ4AeNdg==",
           "length": 15565,
           "stub": true
       }
   }
```

but when I use image from webcam , it gives me blob (image data).
So in JavaScript or jquery How can I convert this blob into image as a file. like...test.jpeg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the webcam image data with `getUserMedia` right?

1. Render the image into a HTML5 canvas element.
2. Execute `getDataUrl` on the canvas
3. Strip off the dataUrl meta data at the beginning of the result

... and you will have a base64 encoded string of the image that you can send to the CouchDB as attachment.

Comment: Not `.getDataUrl` but `.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.95 /*0..1 quality*/)`